# Problem when unchecking checkbox buttons in a form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, ecmascript-6

In my demo form, you can run below, fieldsets are enabled sequentially on button selection. So checking a button in the first fieldset enables the second, and so on.

If all checkboxes are unchecked in the first fieldset, the form should reset and then second to the fourth fieldset should be disabled again.

However, when one of the checkboxes in the first fieldset is deselected, all other checkbox buttons in the first fieldset are also deselected, which of course is not the way it’s supposed to work.

What am I doing wrong?

---

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", _ => {
  const form = document.forms[0]

  // First, disable all fieldsets except the first

  function disableFieldsets() {
    const disabledFieldsets = form.querySelectorAll(
      "section:not(:first-of-type) fieldset"
    )

    for (let i = 0; i < disabledFieldsets.length; i++) {
      disabledFieldsets[i].disabled = true
    }
  }

  disableFieldsets()

  // Sequentially enable fieldsets on selection

  const sections = form.querySelectorAll("section")

  let reset = false
  
  sections.forEach(section => {
    section.addEventListener("change", function() {
      let nextFieldset = this.nextElementSibling.querySelector("fieldset")
      if (nextFieldset && !reset) {
        nextFieldset.disabled = false
      } else if (reset) {
        reset = false
      }
    })
  })

  // Reset form and disable fieldsets after all inputs in the first fieldset are deselected

  const firstFieldsetButtons = form.querySelectorAll("[name=First]")
  let isChecked = false

  firstFieldsetButtons.forEach(firstFieldsetButton => {
    firstFieldsetButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      if (this.checked) {
        isChecked = true
      } else {
        form.reset()
        disableFieldsets()
      }
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<main>
<form method="post" action="">    
  <section>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>First Fieldset</legend>
    <label><input type=checkbox name=First value=A>A</label>
    <label><input type=checkbox name=First value=B>B</label>
    <label><input type=checkbox name=First value=C>C</label>
  </fieldset>
  </section>
  
  <section>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Second Fieldset</legend>
    <label><input type=radio name=Second value=1.1>1.1</label>
    <label><input type=radio name=Second value=1.2>1.2</label>
    <label><input type=radio name=Second value=1.3>1.3</label>
  </fieldset>
  </section>
  
  <section>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Third Fieldset</legend>
    <label><input type=radio name=Third value=2.1>2.1</label>
    <label><input type=radio name=Third value=2.2>2.2</label>
    <label><input type=radio name=Third value=2.3>2.3</label>
  </fieldset>
  </section>
  
  <section>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Fourth Fieldset</legend>
    <label><input type=radio name=Fourth value=3.1>3.1</label>
    <label><input type=radio name=Fourth value=3.2>3.2</label>
    <label><input type=radio name=Fourth value=3.3>3.3</label>
  </fieldset>
  </section>
  
  <input type=submit value=Submit>
</form>
</main>
```

Comment: You're resetting the form by doing `form.reset()` when any of the first fieldset checkboxes have been unchecked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make another condition like this:
`if(this.closest('fieldset').querySelectorAll('input:checked').length > 0) { return;}`

snippet:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", _ => {
  const form = document.forms[0]

  // First, disable all fieldsets except the first

  function disableFieldsets() {
    const disabledFieldsets = form.querySelectorAll(
      "section:not(:first-of-type) fieldset"
    )

    for (let i = 0; i < disabledFieldsets.length; i++) {
      disabledFieldsets[i].disabled = true
    }
  }

  disableFieldsets()

  // Sequentially enable fieldsets on selection

  const sections = form.querySelectorAll("section")

  let reset = false
  
  sections.forEach(section => {
    section.addEventListener("change", function() {
      let nextFieldset = this.nextElementSibling.querySelector("fieldset")
      if (nextFieldset && !reset) {
        nextFieldset.disabled = false
      } else if (reset) {
        reset = false
      }
    })
  })

  // Reset form and disable fieldsets after all inputs in the first fieldset are deselected

  const firstFieldsetButtons = form.querySelectorAll("[name=First]")
  let isChecked = false

  firstFieldsetButtons.forEach(firstFieldsetButton => {
    firstFieldsetButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) { 
      if(this.closest('fieldset').querySelectorAll('input:checked').length > 0) { return;} 
      if (this.checked) {
        isChecked = true
      }
     
      else {
        form.reset()
        disableFieldsets()
      }
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<main>
<form method="post" action="">    
  <section>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>First Fieldset</legend>
    <label><input type=checkbox name=First value=A>A</label>
    <label><input type=checkbox name=First value=B>B</label>
    <label><input type=checkbox name=First value=C>C</label>
  </fieldset>
  </section>
  
  <section>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Second Fieldset</legend>
    <label><input type=radio name=Second value=1.1>1.1</label>
    <label><input type=radio name=Second value=1.2>1.2</label>
    <label><input type=radio name=Second value=1.3>1.3</label>
  </fieldset>
  </section>
  
  <section>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Third Fieldset</legend>
    <label><input type=radio name=Third value=2.1>2.1</label>
    <label><input type=radio name=Third value=2.2>2.2</label>
    <label><input type=radio name=Third value=2.3>2.3</label>
  </fieldset>
  </section>
  
  <section>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Fourth Fieldset</legend>
    <label><input type=radio name=Fourth value=3.1>3.1</label>
    <label><input type=radio name=Fourth value=3.2>3.2</label>
    <label><input type=radio name=Fourth value=3.3>3.3</label>
  </fieldset>
  </section>
  
  <input type=submit value=Submit>
</form>
</main>
```

Comment: Hey, I just tried your suggestion and the form doesn’t reset after the last checked checkbox is unchecked. Can you help?

Comment: wasn't that the expected result?

Comment: No, the form should reset when the last checked checkbox from the first fieldset is unchecked.

Comment: oh. no problem give me a sec

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort! But it still doesn’t work. It still resets the form on first deselection.

Comment: I must don't understand what you mean... The first part won't reset or disable the other fields when uncheck all first fieldset inputs, and the second will reset the form after uncheck them... So when do u want the form will reset? cause you can trigger that specific event and that's it....

Comment: Sorry if I caused you frustration. The form should reset on the very last checkbox deselection in the first fieldset. So if I had all three checkboxes checked, and I start deselecting first A, then B, then form should reset on deselecting C. I hope I clarified it a little. Again, thank you.

Comment: oh! give me another sec

Comment: @Tzar hope i finally get what you ask... check my edit